# MySQL Workbench - "deploying" schema into a real database

Tags: mysql-5.5, mysql-workbench, deployment

a noob here, finding my way around. So, how can I "transfer, deploy or whatever the right term is" the database tables, fields, etc. that I have created with Workbench into a real database?

The dB I have is currently on a local WAMP installation but I also have it on a real web server.

Many thanks,
Alex

EDIT: I wish to use MySQL Workbench to "draw" database tables, columns and all the other info that is needed for a database to function properly and then transfer this onto my server. Meaning, I wish to avoid having to use clunky phpMyAdmin to create database for my application but instead create it on my PC with Workbench and then transfer all this onto real production server. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called either **Forward engineering** (create a new set of schemas + db objects based on your model) or **Synchronization** (apply changes in your model to an existing setup and incorporate changes from that setup into your model). The latter feature works best if you first reverse engineered an existing setup into a model and work from there. Synchronization does a 2-way merge and allows to manually exclude changes from being taken over to the other side or even change the direction for changes, if the automatic detection is not right.